# PyQt4: get list of all labels in QListWidget

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

I am new to PyQt4 and especially the QListWidget. I am trying to get a (Python) list of of all labels currently displayed in the QListWidget. I'm able to to get a list of all the QListWidgetItems, but I'm not sure how to get to the labels from there...

This is what I use to get the list of all the QListWidgetItems:

```
    items = []
    for index in xrange(self.ui.QListWidget.count()):
         items.append(self.ui.QListWidgetitem(index))
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.text()` returns the text within a QListWidgetItem. Note that you need to call `.item(index)` on the original QListWidget instance to get the items contained in the list widget:

```
items = []
for index in xrange(self.ui.QListWidget.count()):
     items.append(self.ui.QListWidget.item(index))
labels = [i.text() for i in items]
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! unfortunales this raises an error:    labels = [i.text() for i in items] 
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'text'`- what am I missing?

Comment: @bigsleep: sorry, I updated the code to properly get the contained items.

Answer (score 2):

You can force list widget to return all items with `findItems`:

```
lst = [i.text() for i in self.lstFiles.findItems("", QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using list comprehension:

```
labels = [list_widget.item(i).text() for i in range(list_widget.count())]
```